# Unexpected behavior using `std::count` on `std::vector` of pairs

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stdvector, counting

My goal is to *completely* remove all elements in a `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>` that occur more than once.

The idea was to utilize `std::remove` with `std::count` as part of the predicate. My approach looks something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using i_pair = std::pair<int, int>;

int main()
{
    std::vector<i_pair> vec;
    vec.push_back(i_pair(0,0)); // Expected to stay
    vec.push_back(i_pair(0,1)); // Expected to go
    vec.push_back(i_pair(1,1)); // Expected to stay
    vec.push_back(i_pair(0,1)); // Expected to go

    auto predicate = [&](i_pair& p)
    {
        return std::count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), p) > 1;
    };
    auto it = std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), predicate);

    cout << "Reordered vector:" << endl;
    for(auto& e : vec)
    {
        cout << e.first << " " << e.second << endl;;
    }
    cout << endl;
    
    cout << "Number of elements that would be erased: " << (vec.end() - it) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The array gets reordered with both of the `(0,1)` elements pushed to the end, however the iterator returned by `std::remove` points at the last element. This means that a subsequent `erase` operation would only get rid of one `(0,1)` element.

Why is this behavior occurring and how can I delete *all* elements that occur more than once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your biggest problem is `std::remove_if` gives very little guarantees about the contents of the vector while it is running.

It guarantees at the end, `begin()` to returned iterator contains elements not removed, and from there until `end()` there are some other elements.

Meanwhile, you are iterating over the container in the middle of this operation.

It is more likely that `std::partition` would work, as it guarantees (when done) that the elements you are "removing" are actually stored at the end.

An even safer one would be to make a `std::unordered_map<std::pair<int,int>, std::size_t>` and count in one pass, then in a second pass remove everything whose count is at least 2.  This is also O(n) instead of your algorithms O(n^2) so should be faster.

```
std::unordered_map<i_pair,std::size_t, pair_hasher> counts;
counts.reserve(vec.size()); // no more than this
for (auto&& elem:vec) {
  ++counts[elem];
}
vec.erase(std::remove_if(begin(vec), end(vec), [&](auto&&elem){return counts[elem]>1;}), end(vec));
```

you have to write your own `pair_hasher`.  If you are willing to accept nlgn performance, you could do

```
std::map<i_pair,std::size_t> counts;
for (auto&& elem:vec) {
  ++counts[elem];
}
vec.erase(std::remove_if(begin(vec), end(vec), [&](auto&&elem){return counts[elem]>1;}), end(vec));
```

Comment: Can I actually increment `counts[elem]` before it has been initialized as `0`? Is that safe?

Comment: @TheBeautifulOrc [`operator[]` initializes values that are missing basically as if by `T()`, which makes `0` for integer types.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) It's the magic of autovivification~~

Comment: @HTNW And, I'm lazy.